# Why $f(x)=\int_1^x\frac{f'(1)}{t}dt$?

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R^+\to \mathbb R$ differentiable such that $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$, for every $x,y\in \mathbb R^+$. I would like to show

$$f(x)=\int_1^x\frac{f'(1)}{t}dt$$

In another words we have to prove $f(x)=f'(1)\ln(x)$ (I solved the integral).

I've been trying a lot without any success.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Hint (assuming you meant $f(xy) = f(x)+f(y)$: Notice that $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \frac{f\left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)}{h}$. Now let $h\rightarrow 0$...

Comment: @JoeyZou interesting, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you have a typo. you want $$f(xy) = f(x) + f(y), 0 < x, y \tag 1 $$
setting $y = 1$ gives you $f(1) = 0.$  hold the $y$ constant and differencing $(1)$ shows you that $$yf'(xy)=f'(x) \tag 2$$ put $x = 1$ in $(2)$ to get $$f'(y) = \frac{f'1)}{y}, f(1) = 0 $$ gives the result

$$f(y) = f'(1)\ln y.  $$

Comment: Great solution, thank you!

Comment: @user42912, you are welcome.